# dimens for different size

Tags: android, layout, screen

I have 2 device
nexus 5(1920x1080) and samsung a50(2340x1080)

I need the layout to be different in height on these devices

I created dimens - (xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi, w1080-h1920, w1080-h2340) but dp for marginBottom was still taken as from xxhdpi in the same way for these devices
and it turns out that everything is beautiful on samsung and on nexus it does not fit into the screen
how can you differentiate?

Answer (score 0):

You should name your values directory for Samsung `values-h2340dp`. Assuming that 2340x1080 are dp, not pixels. You shouldn't use `xhdpi` or any other `*dpi` for dimens.

Docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

Comment: but then on nexus 5 does not fit into the screen

Comment: I assume you have default `values` with dimens.xml. This dimens will be used by nexus and any other devices. If you add `values-h2340dp` with separate dimens, these will be used only if device has height >= 2340dp. Which in your case is Samsung A50 device. If you need something specific also for Nexus, add `values-h1920dp` with dimens for Nexus.